# Identify who has killed a python windows service

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I have a python windows service running in the background on a shared computer. I would like to know who is bad mannered enough to kill my processes without asking.

Is there a way to know which user kills a given service ?

Started reading here, but didn't find what i was looking for.
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/track-session-events.html

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting article I found on this in the following link: 
http://bugslasher.net/2011/04/17/who-the-hell-killed-my-process/.

I have not tried this yet, but would be interested to hear how you get on.

**UPDATE**

In summary you can download debugging tools for Windows (available [here](http://bugslasher.net/2010/10/27/finally-a-simple-way-to-download-the-debugging-tools-for-windows/))

- This includes a version of GFlags (global flags)
- GFlags can be configured to log data when processes are ended (via silent process exit tab)
- Now you should be able to view details of killed processes (including the perpetrator) in event manager

Comment: Could you please quote the salient parts of the article? That way, your answer doesn't suddenly become useless if the article vanishes. Thanks!

Comment: @nneonneo Updated as requested. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, one of the target systems is windows server 2008, so I guess I am out of luck. I was hoping you could access a variable in service framework via the svcStop function of the controlhandler one.

Comment: Please note that GFLAGS needs to be used very very carefully. This is an official recommendation from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549557(v=vs.85).aspx. Hence please ensure that due care is taken in case you go ahead with implementing this feature using GFlags